# PHP throws error when showing SQL Server query that works in SSMS

Tags: php, sql-server, sqlsrv

This query works perfect when executed in SQL Managament Studio:

```
SELECT [UID], Plant, [Truck_n°], AlplaSTOCKBOL, Article, LoadingDate, CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), LoadingDate, 103) as 'LoadingDay', CONVERT(VARCHAR(5), LoadingDate, 14) as 'LoadingTime', Real_Status, New_DH, Comments, 
CASE
    WHEN ((AlplaSTOCKBOL IS NULL OR AlplaSTOCKBOL = '') and LoadingDate < GETDATE() and coalesce(Real_Status, 'NULL') != 'Cancelado') THEN 'C'
    ELSE 'NC'
END AS 'ColorBOL'

FROM (       
 
        SELECT      CONCAT(LA.IdLadeAuftrag, K.IdArtikelVarianten) as 'UID', 'FRBLO1' as 'Plant', LA.IdLadeAuftrag AS 'Truck_n°', LA.LadeDatum AS 'LoadingDate', LA.IdSpediteur AS 'IDTransport', LA.SpediteurBez AS 'TruckCompany', LA.Typ AS 'Type', A.LieferDatum AS 'Deliverydate', AV.Alias AS 'Article', (SELECT MAX(J.JournalNummer) FROM [AlplaPROD_eslef1].[dbo].T_EAIJournal AS J WHERE (J.IdJournalTyp = '6' OR J.IdJournalTyp = '4' OR J.IdJournalTyp = '3') AND J.IdLadeAuftrag = LA.IdLadeAuftrag) AS 'AlplaSTOCKBOL'
        FROM        [AlplaPROD_eslef1].[dbo].V_LadeAuftraege AS LA INNER JOIN
                    [AlplaPROD_eslef1].[dbo].V_LadePlanungen AS LP ON LA.IdLadeAuftrag = LP.IdLadeAuftrag INNER JOIN
                    [AlplaPROD_eslef1].[dbo].V_Konten AS K ON LP.IdKonto = K.IdKonto INNER JOIN
                    [AlplaPROD_eslef1].[dbo].V_Artikelvarianten_BASIS AS AV ON K.IdArtikelVarianten = AV.IdArtikelvarianten INNER JOIN
                    [AlplaPROD_eslef1].[dbo].V_Abrufe AS A ON LP.IdAbrufe = A.IdAbrufe
        WHERE       LA.LadeDatum between DATEADD(HOUR, -24, GETDATE()) and DATEADD(HOUR, 48, GETDATE()) AND LA.Status <>'31'
        GROUP BY    LA.IdLadeAuftrag, LA.LadeDatum, LA.IdSpediteur, LA.SpediteurBez, LA.Typ, A.LieferDatum, AV.Alias, LA.Bemerkung, K.IdArtikelVarianten    
            
) SV

LEFT JOIN [AlplaPROD_eslef1_cus].[dbo].truckviewer_eslef1_outgoing on SV.[UID] = ID
ORDER BY LoadingDate ASC
```

But for some reason, when executed with a PHP Code, it throws the error

```
sqlsrv_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, bool given....
```

If I try a simpler query, like

```
select TOP 50 * from IdLadeAuftrag
```

it also works perfect, so it is not a connection issue.

The only thing that COULD cause problems is because I get data from two different databases, but both are on the same server, and the user also has access to both.

This is the connection string used:

```
<?php

  $serverName = "server_name";
  $connectionInfo = array("Database"=>"database","UID"=>"user","PWD"=>"password");
  $conn = sqlsrv_connect($serverName, $connectionInfo);
 
?>
```

If needed, the PHP code to show the query is:

```
$resultset  = sqlsrv_query($conn, $sql);   # $sql is the query written above
while( $rows = sqlsrv_fetch_array( $resultset, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC ) ) {
## Table written here ##
}
```

Tried everything, even recreating the query with some changes, but I always get the same error.
Would appreciate some insight to find the issue.

With SQL_ERRORS() I get this information:

```
SQLSTATE: 42000
code: 156
message: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'CONVERT'.
SQLSTATE: 42000
code: 102
message: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Incorrect syntax near 'K'.
SQLSTATE: 42000
code: 156
message: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'AS'.
```

Comment: Use `sqlsrv_errors()` to get a meaningful error message

Comment: What is the error? What does `echo "Error (sqlsrv_query): ".print_r(sqlsrv_errors(), true);` return after the `sqlsrv_query()` call? The reason for the error from the question is the fact, that `sqlsrv_query()` returns `false`.

Comment: with sqlsrv_errors() I got more information. Updated main post.

Comment: As with any debugging task, you should try to simplify the SQL as much as you can while still seeing the error (hopefully ending up with a [mcve] to show us, if not identifying the problem yourself). Two things stand out to me here as possible problems: `[Truck_n°]` uses a non-ASCII character in a column name, which might be causing encoding issues; and you have used single quotes for giving output columns names like `as 'LoadingTime'` which I would expect to be `as [LoadingTime]` or `as "LoadingTime"`, but those are just guesses.

Comment: Agree with @IMSoP... PHP doesn't handle Unicode well, first thing I'd do is get rid of the degree symbol in `[Truck_n°]` and see if that fixes things. If it does start exploring things like adding `"CharacterSet" => "UTF-8"` to your connection properties.